# Failing to link button to intent

Tags: java, android

When i try this code which reads what the user has clicked and compares it to the button name it only seems to work for one array rather then the 2nd one. If anybody can see why please help me

```
        case R.id.new_button:
        final CharSequence[] items = {"N", "E", "M", "G"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Pick a difficulty");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if ("N".equals(items[0]))
            {Intent intent = new Intent();
            Intent i0 = new Intent(B.this, Test1.class);

            startActivity(i0);}
            else if ("M".equals(items[2]))
            {Intent intent = new Intent();
            Intent i2 = new Intent(Brain.this, Test2.class);

            startActivity(i2);;}


        }

        }).show();
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Comment: Why do you call show on  builder.setItems()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit** oops sorry i saw the wrong thing let me re-check your code

As your code is now, you will never hit the second part of the if statement since "N" always equals items[0]. So the else will never be execute.

This should work:

```
if ("N".equals(items[item]))
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Intent i0 = new Intent(Brain.this, CropImageActivity.class);
    startActivity(i0);
}
else if ("M".equals(items[item]))
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Intent i2 = new Intent(Brain.this, Test2.class);
    startActivity(i2);
}
```